# How to work with html files in snap?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I begin learning snap framework. I'm trying to render an html file and layout html file ("template") in a simple way. That is to say, I have a shared html file I want to use as a template one for all the page in my website. How can I do that? And, a similar question, how can I render an html file?

UPDATE:

I don't want to add a new level of abstruction. Is there any to avoid using Heist?

Comment: Did you look at [this page](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist)?

Comment: @Bakuriu, I don't want to add a new level of abstruction. Is there any to avoid using Heist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to serve static files is with [serveFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.8.0/docs/Snap-Util-FileServe.html#v:serveFile).  You would probably have something like this in your routes:

```
[ ...your routes here
, ("markup", serveFile "mymarkup.html")
]
```

This makes it so that when a user goes to `http://yoursite/markup`, the file `mymarkup.html` in whatever directory you ran the app from gets served.  If you are trying to serve many different HTML files, a better solution is [serveDirectory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.8.0/docs/Snap-Util-FileServe.html#v:serveDirectory).  You might use it like this:

```
[ ...your routes here
, ("static", serveDirectory "html")
]
```

This makes it so that when a user goes to `http://yoursite/static/mymarkup.html`, the file `html/mymarkup.html` gets served.

For your question of how to make one file be the template for all your pages, that is precisely what Heist does for you!  There are certainly ways to avoid using Heist, but you will probably be reinventing a lot of what Heist does for you.  At the basic level that you're asking about, Heist is pretty straightforward.  All valid HTML files are valid Heist templates.  I would recommend reading through the [tutorial](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist) like Bakuriu mentioned.  I believe Heist's `apply` tag is almost exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: can I use Heist with any other web framework, say, Scotty?

Comment: Yes.  Heist was specifically designed to not depend on anything from Snap.  However, you'll probably have to write a bit more infrastructure code with other frameworks than you would have to do with Snap.  For instance, [this package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-heist) has the small amount of infrastructure code that makes it easier to use Heist with Happstack.